# Padding throws my whole site off?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build an HTML prototype for a school site and am having a problem. When I apply padding: 5px; to my elements like .newscast or .photo_gallery, it throws the whole site off. It makes the element that much bigger on each side! Padding is supposed to push from the inside not on the outside. Try just adding some padding to any of the nested elements, it will happen! I am not really sure what to do about it, but I have included my code without the padding applied.

Thanks for any help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<header>
    <div class="header grid_10">
        <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="main-menu grid_10">
    </div>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="news_reel grid_5">
        <div id="latest_news" class="grid_10">
            <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="old_news grid_10" id="old1">
            <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="old_news grid_10" id="old2">
            <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="old_news grid_10" id="old3">
            <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="old_news grid_10" id="old4">
            <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right_bar grid_5">
        <div class="grid_10" id="newsletter">
            <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
        </div>  

        <div class="grid_10" id="photo-gallery">
            <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_10" id="newscast">
            <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<footer>
    <div class="grid_10 footer_bar">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_10 footer">
        <h1>Dummy Text</h1>
    </div>
</footer>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #e5e5e5;
}

.main-menu {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #1800ea;
}

.news_reel {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

#latest_news {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #c61111;
}

.old_news {
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#old1 {
    background: #295f16;
}

#old2 {
    background: #2527a1;
}

#old3 {
    background: #0da19f;
}

#old4 {
    background: #d00aa5;
}

.right_bar {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#newsletter {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ed337e;
}

#photo-gallery {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #65005c;
}

#newscast {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ebc800;
}

.footer_bar {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #1800ea;
}

.footer {
    height: 180px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You're `<header>` and `<footer>` tags need to be within the `<body>` tag

Comment: One moment, but either way, thats something I have been doing wrong! Thanks.

Comment: Adding padding, by default, will cause your element to get wider/taller. You can prevent this by using [`box-sizing:border-box`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: By the way, I am not a terrible designer, those are dummy colors so that I can see what I am doing.

Comment: Apply the padding to your innermost divs. Padding applies to the element in relation to it's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding is does enlarge the bounds of an element by default. If you want to change that use:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

If you want to work with <=IE8, adjust the width of your boxes accordingly.

Alternatively, if you want to stick with grid.css, you can put a `div` inside each of your current `div`s and set the margin of the inner `div`s, but that's not the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

There exist two different `box-sizing` modes that affect how padding work. The default mode *does* increase the size of an element.

See http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html for an in-depth explanation.